# An issue about connect to database in WPF

Tags: wpf, database-connection

I have a WPF app which will use a custom class to connect to a database.

```
public class SQLRead
{
    public string sql;
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand cmd;

    public SQLRead()
    {
        sql = string.Empty; 
    }

    public void NewConnection()
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(
            @"Data Source = Server\Instance;   
              Integrated Security = SSPI;");
        cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 120;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        conn.Open();
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        conn.Close();
    }

    //public void addParameterVarChar(string s, int size, object value)
    //{
    //    SqlParameter sp = new SqlParameter("@SubRegion", SqlDbType.Char, 1, "B");
    //    //sp.Value = value;
    //    cmd.Parameters.Add(sp);
    //}

    public void AddParameter(string s, object value)
    {
        SqlParameter sp = new SqlParameter(s, value);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(sp);
    }

    public List<string> ReadAlnName()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(conn.ConnectionString);

        sql = @"Select AlignmentName + '::AlnID' + cast(AlnID as varchar(10))
                From [crwdb].[dbo].[Alignment]";
        cmd.CommandText = sql;

        var list = new List<string>();
        using (conn)
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    list.Add((string)reader.GetString(0));
                }
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
        //conn.Dispose();

        return list;
    }

    public static int ParseAlnEntry(string alnEntry)
    {
        Regex reg = new Regex(@"^.+?\:{2}AlnID(\d+)$");
        Match m;
        int alnID = -1;
        if ((m = reg.Match(alnEntry)).Success)
        {
            alnID = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[1].Value);
        }

        return alnID;
    }

    public List<PhylNode> ReadSeqTaxTree(int alnID, int seqTypeId, int locationID, int rootTaxID, int depth)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("\n{0}\n{1}",conn.ConnectionString, sql));

        // SQL query
        sql = @"Execute [crwdb].[dbo].[sp_SeqDistribution] 
                    @AlnID, @SeqTypeID, @LocationID, @RootTaxID, @Depth";
        cmd.CommandText = sql;

        // Add parameters
        AddParameter("@AlnID", alnID);
        AddParameter("@SeqTypeID", seqTypeId);
        AddParameter("@LocationID", locationID);
        AddParameter("RootTaxID", rootTaxID);
        AddParameter("Depth", depth);

        var tree = new List<PhylNode>();

        using (conn)
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                int tmpTaxID, tmpParentID, tmpSeqNum;
                string tmpLineage;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    tmpTaxID = (int)reader.GetInt32(0);
                    tmpParentID = (int)reader.GetInt32(1);
                    tmpLineage = (string)reader.GetString(2);
                    tmpSeqNum = (int)reader.GetInt32(3);
                    if (tmpSeqNum > 0)
                    {
                        tree.Add(new PhylNode(tmpTaxID, tmpParentID, tmpLineage, tmpSeqNum));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
        //conn.Dispose();

        return tree;
    }
}
```

I create an instance of SQLRead, passed it to the next window (through constructor), and then call ReadAlnName method, it works.

```
public partial class DBModeMainWindow : Window
{
    // The database connection
    SQLRead Conn;

    // The phylogenetic tree
    List<PhylNode> tree;

    public DBModeMainWindow(SQLRead conn)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Conn = conn;

        List<string> alnStr = Conn.ReadAlnName();
        AlnViewModel alnVM = new AlnViewModel(alnStr);
        DataContext = alnVM;
    }

    private void buttonGetTree_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedAlnEntry = comboBoxAln.SelectedValue.ToString();
        int alnID = SQLRead.ParseAlnEntry(selectedAlnEntry);
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format(
            "Selected item: {0}. \nAlnID:{1}", selectedAlnEntry, alnID));

        tree = Conn.ReadSeqTaxTree(1, 1, 1, 2, 3);
    }
```

Than I add a button, when user click the button, the code behind will call Conn.ReadSeqTaxTree method. But this time, I got a error "The connectionString is not initaited."

Am I missing something there? Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ThiWhy would you not do NewConnection in the ctor?  Why is string sql; public?  This is messed up.

Comment: Don't put your connection and command in fields; you're begging for trouble. It's too hard to reason about their state when they're shared across so much code. The method that creates a disposable object should also be responsible for disposing it; you're violating that principle all over the place. The pattern should be *one method* that does all of the following: `using (var connection = [create your connection]) { connection.Connect(); using (var command = [create your command]) { [do stuff] } }` Your code will be far clearer, and will probably work too.